How to change rodauth email template based on locale?
I've been attempting to modify the Rodauth email template without success.
By default, my app has a template located at /app/views/rodauth_mailer/verify_account.text.erb.
However, I'd like to customize this template based on locale, such as:
/app/views/rodauth_mailers/hi/verify_account.text.erb
/app/views/rodauth_mailers/en/verify_account.text.erb
Could you please provide guidance on how to achieve this?
How to set up or configure rodauth.

I would expect that Rodauth would find and handle the localized email templates without further configuration when their naming was following Ruby on Rails' default naming conventions for localized views.
Which means that the file should be named like this:

/app/views/rodauth_mailers/verify_account.hi.text.erb
/app/views/rodauth_mailers/verify_account.en.text.erb


@spickermann
Thank you for your suggestion I'll try it later.
Upon further exploration, I've come to the following conclusion:
In the /app/views/rodauth_mailers/verify_account.text.erb,
I'm rendering the following partials:
<%= render partial: "/rodauth_mailer/#{I18n.locale.to_s}/verify_account" %>
<%= render partial: "/rodauth_mailer/#{I18n.locale.to_s}/footer" %>
This setup allows us to conveniently set email templates for each locale by organizing them into separate folders.
For instance:
English templates can be found at:
/app/views/rodauth_mailers/en/_verify_account.text.erb
/app/views/rodauth_mailers/en/_footer.text.erb
Similarly, templates for other locales can be organized accordingly.
